# How to listen to the same song at the same time on 2 different iPhones?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, audio, music

My girlfriend stay far way from me, but we have a habit that is listening to music together in the morning. But now we have to do that by playing loud by a Computer so that the quality is so low. I wonder that any IOS app can help us listen to the same song at the same time, i.e. when I press Play button, the song will be played at the same time in my iPhone and her iPhone too.

Comment: Don't understand why you both can not play the same song using your devices. She would have to press the play as well.

Comment: Some of the streaming services allow you to sort of do this.  If your expecting to both be synched or hearing the same notes or words at the same moment, you won't, due to latency you will never be exactly in synch.

Answer (score 5):

There are couple of young coders who met at 2013 WWDC after getting a scholarships from Apple who had the same idea you describe. They brought out an app called
[Audibly](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/audibly-make-your-music-heard./id882170258?mt=8)

> **Description**
>
> Audibly plays your music in sync across nearby iOS devices. Just
> choose the songs you want, link up some devices, and you're ready to
> go.
>
> Hanging out with friends and want to play a song, but your phone’s
> speakers aren't loud enough? Instantly create a wireless surround
> sound system and forget messy headphone cables.
>
> Features: • Create a playlist of songs from your own library • Control
> the volume across all the devices • Music kept in sync as you listen •
> Use filters to change the pitch of the music • Favorite what’s playing
> to come back to it later • No Internet connection required*
>
> Audibly was first created at WWDC by a group of Student Scholarship
> Recipients: Nick Frey, Chris Galzerano, and Veeral Patel.
>
> - Music can be streamed over Peer-to-Peer Wi-Fi on newer, supported devices, anywhere you are without an Internet connection. Devices can
>   also connect over a Wi-Fi network.

They still have some bugs to iron out but I have used it and it works well.

Comment: The limitation of Audibly to _nearby iOS devices_ would seem to rule it out for this question. Streaming without Internet via local WiFi is much easier technicly, but wouldn't work for a friend in another state.

Comment: @nealmcb, Yes  "far away from me"  could mean in a totally different location in the world. But it could also mean they are in two different areas in a house and rather than blast the music from tiny computer speakers somewhere in the middle. They could each use their iPhones...

Answer (score 2):

If you have your music on a PC or Mac, you could use Rogue Amoeba's [**Airfoil**](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) to send audio from the computer to their **Airfoil Satellite** app on both iPhones, and it should play in sync.

Airfoil Satellite can do basic remote control of some music apps/services (on your PC or Mac) - or if you use iTunes you could use Apple's **iTunes Remote** app to control what you listen to.

Airfoil is commercial software, I don't know of a free equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Grooveshark is a music service à la Spotify and Pandora, with the key feature that you can play any song on demand and to build a playlist in advance.

You can then broadcast the music playing as a station others can tune in to using Grooveshark as well.

Link: http://grooveshark.com

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use a great online platform to listen music from youtube videos called Festa ([www.festa.co](https://www.festa.co))

It's a video player but only focused on music, and the great advantage of Festa is that when you create your account, you will get an account name which you can share with your friends, they can access to that URL from their computers or mobile phones and view your playlist and add songs to that playlist.

The interesting part is that it also show them a button to listen live, so the same music you are playing, they will be able to listen to.

This is an amazing and simple way to listen music with my friends but the only problem now is that listen live function only works if your firends are connected from another Laptop or iMac, it doesn't work on mobile phones yet.

The guys who created the platform are working on that feauterd, but for now it's amazing to listen the same music with my firends and also let them add songs to the playlist in real time. Everything without need to install any software!

Comment: The link seems to lead to a 404 page

Comment: Also please state your affiliation with the platform

Comment: @patrix I'm not affiliated... I'm just the friend of the ceo of that platform :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://www.jqbx.fm if you have spotify. They have an iOS app, website and desktop app. You would just make a private room for the two of you (or I guess you could make it public, your call) then just play tracks back and forth wherever you are.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of options out there. One of the newer ones is https://sunspot.app

The platform allows you to listen to music at the same time as anyone else in the room. You can like tracks, chat with others in the room, and even post instagram/snapchat style comments on the tracks timeline. You can also live stream to the rest of the users in the room... kinda like facebook live. You can set a password on the room as well so that it would be only the two of you.

The idea is that it is meant to be like a Silent Disco for the world wide web, so it should suffice for your needs. You can also toggle between video and audio depending on your desire. You could even upload "movies" or something to watch together and you could watch movies together in realtime.

Note: I am the founder of the application.

Answer (score -2):

AMPME is the exact Application that fulfill your requirements. 
iOS - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ampme-play-music-louder/id986905979?mt=8
Android - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amp.android&hl=en

Comment: Sorry, but we are looking for the reason this app is the best fit to the needs of OP. If you could add this, your answer will better serve the community.

Comment: AMPME is for devices within bluetooth range, not someone in a different state.