# How can I connect multiple wireless headphones to the same iPhone at the same time?

Tags: bluetooth, iphone

I like to listen to audio files on my iPhone 6 while jogging outdoors.

My girlfriend wants to join me (jog with me and have her own headphones listening to the same audio).

How can we *both* pair our wireless headphones to my iPhone simultaneously so that we're listening to exactly the same thing?

(And these audio files are not available in some shared location like Spotify.)

(Also, we own a headphone splitter, but using wired headphones is inconvenient since cords make running difficult.)

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but they call it 'pairing' for a reason - one device, one headset; one pair.

Comment: See also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144985/how-to-listen-to-the-same-song-at-the-same-time-on-2-different-iphones?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would be difficult for the conditions described.

Looking for most portable solution,I think this [BT splitter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004I408OW) might do the job.

http://www.solveyourtech.com/can-two-bluetooth-devices-connected-iphone/

Comment: Any solution for the new iPhone/iPad without the 30 pin plug?

Answer (score 10):

There is another "workaround" that DOESN'T involve Bluetooth. I often train multiple students students for 5K's, 10K's, etc. Since I train multiple students at a time and often use 1-hr long DJ mixes to set paces for everyone, I connect my iPhone to an FM broadcast device (usually limited from a 30-100 feet range). I additionally, I encourage trainees to use wireless devices such as nano shuffles, etc. that can pick up radio FM frequencies. There's no pesky Bluetooth "pairing" compatibility issues and anybody can join in by simply tuning in to my FM frequency; even those with nothing more than a simple portable radio/MP3 player. Although these devices were originally intended for tuning into your car radio, I've found they work just as well as for other mobile devices that can receive radio FM frequencies. They're not that expensive, either.

[Link](https://www.walmart.com/ip/AGPtEK-Wireless-Car-Audio-FM-Transmitter-Bluetooth-Receiver-Speaker-Music-Receiver-Adapter-Hands-Free-for-smartphone/49462846)

Comment: The link seems to be for the transmitter. Do you have a link for the (inexpensive) FM receivers you use?

Answer (score 6):

While it is true that there is no built-in supported method for an iPhone to connect to multiple sets of bluetooth speakers, it is possible to do so.

You would need to get an additional device, a Bluetooth splitter. They generally plug in to the headphone jack, and will connect to at least 2 devices. Likely more finicky than using just an iPhone, but possible. [Here](http://www.monoprice.com/Product?c_id=108&cp_id=10823&cs_id=1082703&p_id=9722&seq=1&format=1) is one example.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, iOS 13 will now have this capability:

https://9to5mac.com/2019/05/26/report-iphone-11-could-let-users-send-music-to-two-bluetooth-devices-at-the-same-time/

Comment: Interesting. That article also says "Dual Bluetooth Audio is part of the Bluetooth 5 specification, although it’s not clear if the Bluetooth 5 radios present in the iPhone since 2017 can support it. If so, it is possible Apple could also add this feature to iPhone 8, iPhone X, iPhone XR, and iPhone XS with a software update." Can anyone here confirm that this works? (Mention which model of phone you have and what software version, please.)

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled across this after looking at the JBL Synchros E40BT over the ear headphones sold at Crutchfield.

It looks like you are basically just pairing one set to the iPhone/ipod etc.  But, the headphones allow you to pair a "secondary" set to the first.  The primary set controls the music but the second pair hears exactly what the first is hearing.

Answer (score 1):

I just bought two SkyGenius over ear headphones on amazon, you can connect two SkyGenius headphones to one iPhone without any splitter, they name this function ‘ShareMe’, you can make the two headphones pairing first, and then pair one of them to your iPhone, then the two headphones can listen simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Apple is rolling this capability out.  The feature is called [Airplay](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202809), and both the iPhone or whatever broadcasting device and the headphones must support the standard for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

MyStream is an app that lets you share that music wirelessly to your friend's iDevice so you can both listen to the same music at the same time.